# Что за метка [str]?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки

Я не давно увидел метку [str](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/str), у неё нет описания.

Что это за метка? Её очень часто используют в смысле встроенной функции `str` в python, но иногда и в качестве [строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8).

**Так зачем она нужна?**

Comment: По-моему, надо просто объединить со [tag:строки]

Comment: @αλεχολυτ правильно!

Answer (score 4):

Метка явно о строках, поэтому объединил её со [строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8):

```
updating post history, 54 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 47 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 39 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'str': [str] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 3858
tag remapping of [строки] and [str] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
2 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym str -> строки was approved!
```